# use klepto to cache by function name and args

Tags: python, klepto

I'm trying to use klepto as a cache which hashes off the args and function name, is this possible?

e.g. so using a dir_cache i would be able to

```
@inf_cache(cache=dir_archive(cached=False))
def func1(x, y):
    return x + y

@inf_cache(cache=dir_archive(cached=False))
def func2(x, y):
    return x - y
```

and both calls to func1(1, 2) and func2(1, 2) would result in separate keys in the dir_archive

am i missing something?

Comment: I'm the `klepto` author.  I'm not clear what you are looking for.  Do you want both `func1` and `func2` to cache to the same `dir_archive`… but the "sub-caches" to remain distinct for each function?  If that's the case why not just use two different directories?  Basically, cache function `func1` in directory `./func1` and function `func2` in `./func2`?  All you'd need to add is `name='func1'` for the first `dir_archive` and `name='func2'` for the second.

Comment: Hi there, I'm looking to make the name of the function part of the key of the cahe, as well as the args. Then I can use the same archive without using name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although probably not a totally robust solution, this seems to do what you want at some level.

```
>>> import klepto 
>>> @klepto.inf_cache(cache=klepto.archives.dir_archive(cached=False))
... def func1(x, y, name='func1'):
...   return x+y
... 
>>> @klepto.inf_cache(cache=klepto.archives.dir_archive(cached=False))
... def func2(x, y, name='func2'):
...   return x-y
... 
>>> 
>>> func1(1,2)
3
>>> func1(1,3)
4
>>> func2(2,4)
-2
>>> func2(1,2)
-1
>>> func1.__cache__()
dir_archive('memo', {-8532897055064740991: 4, -8532897055063328358: 3, -960590732667544693: -1, -3289964007849195004: -2}, cached=False)
>>> 
>>> func1(1,2)        
3
>>> func1(1,2)
3
>>> func2(1,2)
-1
>>> 
>>> func1.__cache__() == func2.__cache__()
True
```

You'll note that the `dir_archive` is the same, and the functions both appear to use individual caches.  One issue, would be that you could pass in a `'name'` to override the default, and mess things up easily.  I'm guessing that you could do something more robust if needed with another decorator to prevent the user from changing the `'name'` keyword.